# NodeJS, Copying text from another application

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi guys I have a problem which I have couldn't solve after researching for quite some time. It is the following:

The copying of text from the GUI of another application (without having access to the other application programmatically)

For example:

1. copy the text of a word file while the application is open and is being worked on.
2. copy the text of an email while a email application is open and is being worked on.

I am not even sure if this is possible but would love any suggestions.

Comment: AutoIt has interesting features, maybe some of them some can help(?)... Or some test framework ? Suppose there should be something similar for node.js too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can capture the screen then use OCR's technique to extract text from image.

Comment: OCR seems interesting